# Duda con el Toast en respuesta a Zxing code QR

Tags: android, qrcode, android-toast

Quiero saber si hay alguna de forma de lograr que el mensaje se muestre en el Toast de manera diferente.

He creado un lector de codigo QR que funciona con zxing. Al escanear el código, el resultado se envía a un toast. Quiero que el mensaje que resulte del código QR se muestre en otra ventana y si es un enlace que me permita abrirlo con el navegador predeterminado de mi teléfono móvil.

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements ZXingScannerView.ResultHandler{
    private ZXingScannerView zXingScannerView;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    }

    public void scan(View view){
        zXingScannerView =new ZXingScannerView(getApplicationContext());
        setContentView(zXingScannerView);
        zXingScannerView.setResultHandler(this);
        zXingScannerView.startCamera();

    }

    @Override
    protected void onPause() {
        super.onPause();
        zXingScannerView.stopCamera();
    }

    @Override
    public void handleResult(Result result) {
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),result.getText(),Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        zXingScannerView.resumeCameraPreview(this);

    }
}
```

Comment: Podrías editar tu respuesta y añadir el codigo que utilizas para leer el codigo QR.

Comment: se puede modificar lo que hace ZXing con el código, ero depende de tu implementación. Como dice @David hacen falta detalles en la pregunta.

Comment: Espero puedan ayudarme amigos. de verdad estoy aprendiendo y las ayudas y comentarios me sacan de dudas.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Supongo que lo que recibes del QR es simple texto, te sugiero lo siguiente:

```
try{
   URL url = Uri.parse(stringRespuesta));
   Intent browserIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, url);
   startActivity(browserIntent);
catch(Exception e){
  //La respuesta no es una url
  Intent intent = new Intent(this, OtraActividad.class);
  intent.putExtra("respuesta", stringRespuesta);
  startActivity(intent);
}
```

Automáticamente intent de la url te abrirá el navegador determinado y si no es una url entonces te mandara a otra actividad donde podrás recibir la respuesta de este modo:

```
Bundle bundle = getIntent().getExtras();
String respuesta = bundle.getString("respuesta");
```

Buena suerte!

Comment: Muchas gracias, donde podria incluir este codigo, en que sección. URI abrira el navegador del dispositivo?